# Significance of number 960 on a Brahmanic stone marker and number 1020 on a Vaishnavite monument?

Tags: symbols, numbers

[image]

The figure shows a "Brahmanic stone marker" from Khmer art (National Museum of Phnom Penh, No. 3058, Angkor Period). The stele shows at its 4 sides in 16 rows and 15 columns

960 = 4 x 16 x 15

identical icons.

What is the significance of the number 960 on the stele?

Note. There exists a similar stele with 1020 icons from Preah Khan, now at Paris (Musée Guimet, No.18104, Vaishnavite monument).

Comment: Jo, this is not really a question about Hinduism. Numerology is considered an ancient Indian science, but separate from the Vedas (it is mentioned in the Upanishads as separate). If this were a question about Western numerology would you post it on the Christianity Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda IMO due to its title and the relief on top this stele links to Hinduism. Also the similar stele from Musée Guimet is annotated as Vaishnavite monument.

Comment: Is this a 1-sided stone or 4-sided? Also, looks like 16x15 (not 17x15)? Assuming 4 sides, it's then 4x16x15 = 960?

Comment: @sv. You are right! I corrected the number to 960, the stele is 4-sided. Nevertheless the stele from Musèe Guimet has 1020 icons.